# Upload a template text file, replace a word with an html table and download the complete file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ms-word, libreoffice

With the following code I can upload to the browser a template text file (docx, odt ..) which inside has the word "**text-to-replace**" in a precise place:

```js
      const fileInput = $('#fileInput');
      const uploadButton = $('#uploadButton');
      const fileNameDisplay = $('#fileName');
    
      uploadButton.on('click', function () {
        fileInput.click();
      });
    
      fileInput.on('change', function () {
        const selectedFile = fileInput[0].files[0];
        if (selectedFile) {
          fileNameDisplay.text(`File uploaded: ${selectedFile.name}`);
    
        } else {
          fileNameDisplay.text(''); // if user delete operation
        }
      });
```

I would like my html table to appear in the file instead of the "**text-to-replace**" and then download the complete file template + html table formatted correctly at the precise point.

Tabella esempio contenuta nel `var allTableDataHTML`

```html
"<table class='tabulator-print-table'><thead><tr><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>ID</th><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>Zoom</th><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>LAYER: Edifici</th><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>TIPO EDIFICIO</th><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>QuotaBase</th><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>QuotaGronda</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class='tabulator-print-table-row'><td>1</td><td><i class='far fa-magnifying-glass-plus'></i></td><td>Edifici</td><td>Edificio civile</td><td>247.81</td><td>250.09</td></tr><tr class='tabulator-print-table-row'><td>2</td><td><i class='far fa-magnifying-glass-plus'></i></td><td>Edifici</td><td>Edificio civile</td><td>248.7</td><td>249.23</td></tr></tbody></table><table class='tabulator-print-table'><thead><tr><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>ID</th><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>Zoom</th><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>LAYER: Stradario</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class='tabulator-print-table-row'><td>3</td><td><i class='far fa-magnifying-glass-plus'></i></td><td>Stradario</td></tr></tbody></table><table class='tabulator-print-table'><thead><tr><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>ID</th><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>Zoom</th><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>LAYER: Civici</th><th colspan='1' rowspan='1'>NUM. CIVICO</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class='tabulator-print-table-row'><td>4</td><td><i class='far fa-magnifying-glass-plus'></i></td><td>Civici</td><td>14</td></tr><tr class='tabulator-print-table-row'><td>5</td><td><i class='far fa-magnifying-glass-plus'></i></td><td>Civici</td><td>13</td></tr></tbody></table>"
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.